# Angularjs Directive Sharing the same scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to identify why the scope is being shared from the same directive. I have this:

```
 <locator-service 
    component="redirect" 
    url="/api/getAllLas1"
    redirect="true"></locator-service>


<locator-service 
   component="signup" 
   url="/api/getAllLas2"
   redirect="false"></locator-service>
```

Which is basically a directive to handle locations (it works perfectly)

here is the directive for this class

```
var app = angular.module("frog").directive('locatorService', LocatorService);

function LocatorService() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/scripts/frog/location-service.html',
        controller: 'locatorController',
        controllerAs: 'locatorController',
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {
            component: "@",
            url: "@",
            redirect: "@"
        }
    }
}
```

I have the "scope" declared, I read on a few threads that this would create an isolated scope.

here is the controller class (minimised)

```
angular.module("frog").controller('locatorController', LocatorController);

function LocatorController($scope, $rootScope, $http, $interval, $document) {

    var self = this;

    $scope.$watch('url', function () {
        if (self.url === undefined) return;
        console.log(self.url);
    })


}
```

I attached the debugger to 'console.log(self.url);' and it printed out the following:

```
/api/getAllLas2
/api/getAllLas2
```

Could someone help me identify why this is happening?
I have an example on my Github that works perfectly fine for directives not sharing the same scope, but it uses $scope (which I have tried to implement but never even worked slightly)

https://github.com/zackdavidson/tappers-web/tree/master/public/scripts/tappers/app/components/transaction

Comment: Try to change `url: "@"` to `url: "="`

Comment: Everything works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/t9t2qc6f/

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov i have tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: @MaximShoustin it does work on jsfiddle actually; but it doens't work on my local machine for some weird reason, that's why i am confused

Comment: well, I have nothing to do with your local machine. compare angular versions, commit redundant code, debug .. Or reproduce your issue in Fiddle I posted